# How do i merge these queries into 1

Tags: c#, linq

So i have below queries.
I would really like to merge these into 1 query.
Next to the fact that this results in an empty collection (which it shouldn't)
My brain just imploded when i tried making this into 1 query.

So if it's not clear from the code
I want to select all horses from a certain user. that have not been signed up for the race that the user is trying to sign up for.

```
var userhorses = (from h in entities.Horses
                          where h.UserId == id
                          select h);

var race = (from r in entities.Races
                    where r.Id == id
                    select r).Single();

var runninghorses = (from rh in race.RacingHorses
                     where rh.UserId == id
                     select rh);

var nonracinghorses = (from nrh in userhorses
                       from rh in runninghorses
                       where nrh.Id != rh.Id
                       select nrh).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

```
public class Horse
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? GenderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public int? ColorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    public int? LegTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual LegType LegType { get; set; }
    public int? CharacterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Character Character { get; set; }
    public int Hearts { get; set; }
    public bool Retired { get; set; }
    public bool CPU { get; set; }
    public bool ForSale { get; set; }
    public int ListPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }
    // Parents
    public int? SireId { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Sire { get; set; }
    public int? DamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Dam { get; set; }
    // Internals
    public int Stamina { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Sharp { get; set; }
    // Special
    public int Dirt { get; set; }
    // Externals
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Corner { get; set; }
    public int OutOfTheBox { get; set; }
    public int Competing { get; set; }
    public int Tenacious { get; set; }
    public int Spurt { get; set; }
    //Future
    public virtual ICollection<Race> FutureRaces { get; set; }
    //RaceResults
    public virtual ICollection<RaceResult> RaceResults { get; set; }
    //Training
    public virtual ICollection<Training> TrainingResults { get; set; }
    //Bids
    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }

    public Horse() {
        ForSale = false; //default value
        Deadline = null;
    }
}


public class Race
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Purse is required")]
    public int Purse { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Slots are required")]
    public int Slots { get; set; }
    public int SlotPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RaceTime { get; set; }

    //public int? TrackId { get; set; }
    //public virtual Track Track { get; set; }

    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Horse> RacingHorses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RaceResult> RaceResults { get; set; }

    public Race()
    {
        SlotPrice = 0; //default value
        Slots = 8;


    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to make your code fail more efficiently? First, make it succeed, inefficiently if necessary.

Comment: not trying to make it fail more succesfully. besides fixing it i want to fix it the right way.

Comment: Don't worry about making it faster until you've made it correct. That's called "premature optimization".

Comment: I would guess your error is in the inconsistent use of `id`. In the `race` query it seems to be referring to a race, but in the other 2 queries it seems to refer to a user.

Comment: That's not it i only have 1 user and this is the first generated race. so the id is the same. obviously i fixed that mistake but that's not why it's broken.

Comment: @Puzzle84: Nothing is "obvious" until you post the correct code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all kudo's go to nmclean for this one.

```
public static SelectList GetNonRacingHorses(int id, int raceId)
{
    HorseTracker entities = new HorseTracker();

    var race = entities.Races.Single(r => r.Id == raceId);
    var racehorses = from h in race.RacingHorses
                     select h.Id;

    var userhorses = (from h in entities.Horses
                      where
                          h.UserId == id
                      orderby h.Name
                      select h);

    var nonracinghorses = from h in userhorses
                          where !racehorses.Contains(h.Id)
                        select h;

    List<SelectListItem> sli = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (Horse horse in nonracinghorses)
    {
        sli.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = horse.Name, Value = horse.Id.ToString(), Selected = false});
    }

    return new SelectList(sli, "Value", "Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the "let" keyword?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx

It also seems you could take benefit of the "except" functionality

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

(Since I don't have the reputation to make a comment, why are you reusing the variable "id" for both User and identifying a race?)

Additional suggestion is you can filter inside the Single

```
var race = entities.Races.Single(r => r.Id == raceId);
```

Comment: I had not, didn't know it existed looking that up now.

Comment: Great catch. sometimes you need that 2nd pair of eyes. looking at that now. Ok that didn't fix it because i'm testing with the 1st user i didn't catch that earlier :D. lookinf at let now

Answer (score 0):

I am making these assumptions:

- you have `id`, the user ID
- you have `raceId`, the ID of the race being signed up for
- there is an `entities.RacingHorses` collection which is the associations of race and horse IDs

Then you could use:

```
from h in entities.Horses
where h.UserId == id
let rhs = entities.RacingHorses.Where(rh => rh.HorseId == h.Id)
where !rhs.Any(rh => rh.RaceId == raceId)
select h
```

Breakdown:

- `h` = a user's horse
- `rhs` = RacingHorses associations for `h`
- if `raceId` appears in `rhs`, then `h` is signed up for that race; do not select this `h`

Comment: That is very correctly assumed :D testing this now :D Actually minor changes there. each race has a collection racinghorses. i don't have an entity for racing horses but for race

Comment: @Puzzle84 If a race has a collection of horses, does a horse have a collection of races as well (or a RaceID)?

Comment: Nope. Horse has an id Race has an id. Race has a collection of horse id's. Perhaps i should add that to the horse to circumvent this situation

Comment: If you can add collections, that could greatly simplify the query to something like "from h in user.Horses where h.Races does not contain race".

Comment: var userhorses = (from h in entities.Horses where h.UserId == id orderby h.Name select h);

var nonracinghorses = userhorses.Except(race.RacingHorses);

That works when there aren't any horses registered to the race.
but the second i've added one i get the following error:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'DOCCL.Models.Horse'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: editted the first post so you guys can see the models i'm using now.

Comment: @Puzzle84 That error occurs because EF doesn't know how to convert that query into SQL. I think you could do this in 2 steps: (1.) Select all the horse IDs from race.RacingHorses into a list (2.) Select userhorses where `!listOfIds.Contains(h.Id)`. EF would then be able to convert that to "select from horse where id not in (...)" There is probably a better way though, so I would suggest you post a separate EF question for this.